# Autosuggestion is not working on my search engin

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have implemented dbsight on my server. It is working fine. Just one option is missing: it is not showing me autosuggestion on the search result page like in the demo page:

```
http://search.dbsight.com/search.do?indexName=freedb&q=u2+beautiful+day
```

In my search result page it is not displaying me suggestion list.
I have found the suggest.ftl file but it's doesn't produce anything.
You can check it over here.http://filesinn.com/

search the term and I show the ajax call on the firebug console but it will not populate suggestion list.

Can any one help me out?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

They do use the jquery.suggest.js for this I think:

http://search.dbsight.com/templates/freedb/html/resource/jquery.suggest.js

To acitvate it on your input field with `id="q"`.

```
jQuery(function() {
 jQuery("#q").suggest("suggest.do?indexName=freedb",
 {
  minchars:1
 });
});
```

It make a query like this on keypess:

http://search.dbsight.com/suggest.do?indexName=freedb&q=u2+beautiful+d

Comment: Yes it is also included in my file. but it's not working. do you have any idea. i already have checked the js file.

Comment: I added some code. Do you have this too? You input has id="q"?

Answer (score 0):

At first I also fall in the trap of thinking that you had implemented autocomplete on your homepage. But after spending some time I realized that was not autocomplete from the server what I saw, but the **browser autocomplete**.

In your homepage you better add the `autocomplete="off"` attribute to your input field in order to disable the browser from helping the user with autocompletion from all the history of things he typed in a field named "q".

Then keep learning from the DBSight documentation:

- [Integration with existing systems - Step 2 Add javascripts](http://wiki.dbsight.com/index.php?title=Integration_with_existing_systems#Step_2_Add_javascripts) (for you homepage only):

  ```
  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="http://filesinn.com/search/search.nocache.js"></script>
  <script language="javascript">
  function dbsightOnLoad(){
      new dbsight.Searcher().server("http://filesinn.com/dbsight")
             .indexName("foxsaver")
      .setup();
  }
  </script>
  ```
- [How to add/customize Suggest-As-You-Type?](http://wiki.dbsight.com/index.php?title=Embeddable_Javascript_Widget#How_to_add.2Fcustomize_Suggest-As-You-Type.3F)

  ```
  var s = new dbsight.Searcher();
  s.addSuggestion();
  ```